# Find $f(x,y)$ integrable such that $f_x(y)$ isn't integrable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Find $f(x,y)$ integrable such that $f_x(y)$ isn't integrable, where $f_x(y)$ is in fact $f(x,y)$ while $x$ is a parameter. I thought of using $\log$ in some variation, but I think it is problematic because $x$ will still be restricted. I am also not sure if I have to to refer this using formal theorems regarding measurement of Jordan or so with sets and volumes, or just to find a continuous function whose continuity is broken once one of the variables is a parameter. I would appreciate your saying in this.

Comment: Do you know Fubini's theorem. If not take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Comment: I do know but don't understand how it can help me. If the integral exists on (x,y) then both orders of integration exist and equal, which means $f_x$ would have to be integrable, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, then $f_x$ is integrable for almost all $x$

Comment: I have to find an example in which $f_x(y)=g(y)$ isn't integrable.

Comment: But if $f(x,y)$ is integrable, how would $f_x(y)$ not be integrable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f \colon [0,1]^2 \to \mathbf R$ by 
$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac 1y & x = 0, y >0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$
Then $f$ is integrable with integral 0 (note that $f = 0$ almost everywhere), but $f_0$ isn't integrable, as $\int_0^1 \frac 1y \, dy = \infty$.

Comment: isn't $f_0(y)=0$ by the conditions above?

Comment: You are right, have corrected my definition of $f$.

Comment: I just got it as soon as I checked. Thank you.

Comment: How come $f_0(y)=1/y$? Isn't $f_x$ partial derivative?

Comment: No. In the OP, $f_x $ denotes the partial function $f_x (y) = f (x,y) $

Answer (score 1):

Here is another more convoluted example, valid for integrability in Riemann's sense (the example in the accepted answer is not Riemann integrable, since it is not bounded.)
$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } x\notin\mathbb{Q},\\
0 & \text{if } x\in\mathbb{Q},\ y\notin\mathbb{Q}\\
1/q & \text{if } x\in\mathbb{Q},\ x=p/q\text{ irreducible fraction, and }y\in\mathbb{Q}.
\end{cases}
$$
It can be shown that $f$ is continuous at every $(x,y)$ with $x$ irrational, proving that $f$ is integrable. If $x$ is rational, $x=p/q$ irreducible fraction,
 then
$$
f_x(y)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } y\notin\mathbb{Q}\\
1/q & \text{if } y\in\mathbb{Q},
\end{cases}
$$
which is not Riemann integrable.